# How to load view from the UIView Controller? Clarification needed

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller

I know this is very basic, but after massive refactoring, i remain a bit confused.

I have a scene created with the help of a storyboard. When a button on a main menu screen is tapped, a `GameView` should load.

`GameView` has a controller `GameViewController`

When the program runs, the GameViewController is called that in turn

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self setGameView:[[GameView alloc] initWithFrame
                  :CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 480)]];
    [self setView:[self gameView]];
    [self loadView];

}
```

What shows on the simulator, however is not a `GameView`, but a mock up created via the Storyboard.

What am i missing please?

I also tried the following in `UIViewController` to no avail

```
UIView *gameView = [[GameView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 480)];

[[[self view] superview] addSubview:gameView];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider

```
UIView *gameView = [[GameView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 480)];

[[self view] addSubview:gameView];
```